# Chromium OS‎ binaries

Tags: chrome-os, chromium-os

Are there any uptodate Chromium OS‎ binaries available? I only found [chromeos.hexxeh.net](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net), but the packages are quite old.

Answer (score 1):

The latest x86 image can be found here http://arnoldthebat.co.uk/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

If you want stable binary, you may use "canal build".
http://www.canal.mokuren.ne.jp/ChromiumOS/usb.html
But this kernel version is old.